# Why is the GHZ state not rotationally symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, symmetry, quantum-entanglement

Consider three spin-1/2 systems. Prepare them in the GHZ state:

$|GHZ\rangle=\frac{|+z,+z,+z\rangle + |-z,-z,-z\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$

Suppose one measures spin along the X axis for all three systems. If I have changed basis correctly, the only possible combinations are the following:

$|+x,+x,+x \rangle; |+x,-x,-x \rangle; |-x,-x,+x \rangle; |-x,+x,-x \rangle$

Instead, if I have changed basis correctly, for a measurement on the y axis, all eight combinations are possible (i.e have a non-zero amplitude):

$|+y,+y,+y \rangle; |+y,+y,-y \rangle; |+y,-y,+y \rangle; |+y,-y,-y \rangle; |-y,+y,+y \rangle; |-y,+y,-y \rangle; |-y,-y,+y \rangle; |-y,-y,-y \rangle$

However, it seems to me that the GHZ state should be symmetric for rotations around the z-axis: only one direction (the z-direction) is selected by the state? I am not sure where I am going mistaken, any help would be much appreciated!

***Edit:***

As noted in the comments, I should have explicitly included the basis change. Here it is:

$|\pm z\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+x\rangle \pm |-x \rangle)
$

Therefore:

$|\pm z, \pm z, \pm z\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|+x, +x, +x\rangle \pm | +x, +x, -x \rangle \pm |+x, -x, +x\rangle + |+x, -x, -x\rangle \pm |-x, +x, +x\rangle + |-x, +x, -x\rangle \pm |-x, -x, -x\rangle)
$

Similarly for y:

$|\pm z\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+y\rangle \pm i |-y \rangle)
$

Therefore:

$|z, z, z\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|+y, +y, +y\rangle + | +y, +y, -y \rangle + |+y, -y, +y\rangle + |+y, -y, -y\rangle + |-y, +y, +y\rangle + |-y, +y, -y\rangle + |-y, -y, -y\rangle)
$

And:

$|-z, -z, -z\rangle= \frac{i}{\sqrt{8}}(|+y, +y, +y\rangle - | +y, +y, -y \rangle - |+y, -y, +y\rangle + |+y, -y, -y\rangle - |-y, +y, +y\rangle + |-y, +y, -y\rangle - |-y, -y, -y\rangle)
$

As @michael correctly explains in the comments, while in the x basis some terms cancel out, in the y they do not, due to the $i$.

Comment: Indeed, I think that your calculation is incorrect and some of the amplitudes in the $y$ case should cancel out. Why don't you write out the basis change and resulting state more explicitly.

Comment: Show your work. Your "if" is a big IF.

Comment: What is your question precisely?

Comment: But GHZ states are not rotationally symmetric! This is why, for example, they are optimal for sensing magnetic fields pointed along one axis but not optimal for other axes. Ahh, you said symmetric for rotations about the $z$-axis. This is also not true, as they become orthogonal to themselves for rotations about the $z$-axis by $\pi/n$, where $n$ is the number of spins (they are unchanged by rotations of $2\pi/n$)

Comment: So, if $n$ is an even integer greater than 2, then rotations of $\pi/2$ will leave the state unchanged, so the $x$ and $y$ axes might start to look the same in that case...

Comment: @Rococo I've gone through the basis change explicitly myself and I get:$$|\pm z,\pm z, \pm z\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \left[ | +x,+x,+x\rangle \pm | +x,+x,-x\rangle \pm | +x,-x,+x\rangle \pm | -x,+x,+x\rangle + | -x,-x,+x\rangle + | +x,-x,-x\rangle + | -x,+x,-x\rangle \pm | -x,-x,-x\rangle \right]$$$$| + z, +z, +z \rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \left[ | +y,+y,+y\rangle + | +y,+y,-y\rangle + | +y,-y,+y\rangle + | -y,+y,+y\rangle
 + | -y,-y,+y\rangle + | +y,-y,-y\rangle + | -y,+y,-y\rangle + | -y,-y,-y\rangle \right]$$...

Comment: ...$$| - z, -z, -z \rangle= \frac{i}{\sqrt{8}} \left[ | +y,+y,+y\rangle - | +y,+y,-y\rangle - | +y,-y,+y\rangle - | -y,+y,+y\rangle
 + | -y,-y,+y\rangle +  | +y,-y,-y\rangle + | -y,+y,-y\rangle - | -y,-y,-y\rangle \right]$$From this we can see that an equal-amplitude superposition of $| + z, + z, +z \rangle$ and $| - z, -z, -z \rangle$ will have several terms cancel out in the $x$-basis, but none of the terms will cancel out in the $y$-basis because of that pesky $i$ out in front of the $| - z, -z, -z \rangle$ state.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSeifert . Looking more closely, I see that you and OP are correct. As a mark of penance I will submit an answer if this gets reopened (as I voted to do), but in case it does not I will say simply that I think the basic question of the OP is still the same, with a clearer resolution, if you consider the state $|+z\rangle + |-z\rangle$ instead of the GHZ state.

Comment: In other words, literally any state can be written in the z basis, so the existence of that representation doesn't tell you anything about whether the state is rotationally symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's key assumption is that "the GHZ state should be symmetric for rotations around the z-axis: only one direction (the z-direction) is selected by the state."

This is incorrect.

One way to see this is to note that the state $|x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+z\rangle+|-z\rangle\right)$ clearly picks out one direction as special. Within the context of a collection of spins 1/2, the transverse directions are defined by a particular phase relationship between up and down, so there is no reason to expect that a state like the GHZ state is symmetric between $x$ and $y$ in general.

As a minor point, the OP defined the basis change as:
$$| \pm z\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+y\rangle \pm i|-y\rangle)$$

But the conventional definition would be the reverse of this:
$$| \pm y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+z\rangle \pm i|-z\rangle);$$
$$| z\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+y\rangle + |-y\rangle);$$
$$| -z\rangle=\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}(|+y\rangle - |-y\rangle);$$

However, the calculation done by the OP for the GHZ state is actually correct for this standard definition, so this does not affect the main point.

Comment: That’s correct, thank you. This made me realise an interesting (surely well-known) general fact about spin-1/2 systems (or two level systems). There is no pure state such that outcomes for spin in an arbitrary direction are equally probable (i.e. probability of spin up/down = 50%, probability of spin left/right=50% etc…)
One can easily see this by looking at the Bloch sphere.

Comment: That's right, but you should be aware (if you aren't already) that there are certain special entangled states that *are* rotationally symmetric. For example, the singlet state $|\psi\rangle = (|+z,-z\rangle -|-z,+z\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. However, you should be able to convince yourself with a bit of thought that these states are only possible for an even number of spins.

Comment: True. Very interesting, thanks!